# datatables con scrollY desacomoda encabezado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, datatables

si m pueden ayudar les agradecere
Tengo varias tablas q las genero dinamicamente depende de los registros de la DB, las pongo dentro de unos acordiones donde el usuario las consultara si las necesita, las convierto a DataTable y le concedo un scrollY y otras caracteristicas, el problema esta q al generar la pagina y mostrar dichas tablas q no se encontraban visibles pk estaban dentro del accordion m genera el encabezado mas pequenno q el resto de la tabla como muestro en la foto si le doy a alguno de los sort del header automaticamente se arregla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma genero mis tablas:

```
<div class="accordion md-accordion accordion-1 mb-1" id="accordion-open-bets" role="tablist">
                <% lista.ForEach(players =>
                {%>
                     <div class="card mb-1">      
                         <% string[] playername = playerBets.Player.Split(' '); %>
                         <div class="card-header mdb-color lighten-1 mask waves-effect waves-block 
                             rgba-white-slight" role="tab" id="<%=playername[1] %>">
                             <a class="white-text collapsed a-collapsable mt-n2 mb-n2" table="<%=playername[1] %>" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse<%=playername[1] %>" aria-expanded="true"
                                 aria-controls="collapse96">
                                 <div class="form-row">
                                     <h5 class="col-6 mt-n1 mb-n1"><%=playerBets.Player %> (<%=playerBets.Pass %>)</h5>
                                     <div class="col-6 mt-n1">
                                         <i class="icon-accordion fas fa-angle-down float-right ml-1 rotate-icon"></i>
                                         <span class="d-inline-block float-right ml-1 little-size-font"></span>
                                         <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half float-right"></i>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </a>
                         </div>
                         <div id="collapse<%=playername[1] %>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<%=playername[1] %>"
                             data-parent="#accordion-open-bets">
                             <div class="card-body ml-n3 mr-n3 ml-md-0 mr-md-0">
                                 <div class="table-responsive">
                                     <table width="100%" id="table<%=playername[1] %>" class="d-table table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
                                         <thead class="mdb-color lighten-1 text-white">
                                             <tr>
                                                 <th>Placed</th>
                                                 <th>Game Date</th>
                                                 <th>Sport</th>
                                                 <th>Description</th>
                                                 <th>Risk/Win</th>
                                             </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                         <%if (playerBets.Bets.Count > 0)
                                             {
                                                 playerBets.Bets.ForEach(betop =>
                                                 {%>
                                         <tr>
                                             <td class="text-break">
                                                 <%=betop.Placed %>
                                             </td>
                                             <td class="text-break">
                                                 <%=betop.GameDate %>
                                             </td>
                                             <td class="text-break">
                                                 <%=betop.Sport %>
                                             </td>
                                             <td class="text-break">
                                                 <%=betop.Description %>
                                             </td>
                                             <td class="text-break">
                                                 <%=betop.RiskWin %>
                                             </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <%});
                                             }
                                         %>
                                     </table>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                <%}); %>
            </div>
```

y las inicializo asi:

```
$('table.d-table').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            paging: false,
            info: false,
            sort: true,
            //scrollCollapse: true,
            scrollY: "400px",
            "columns": [
                { "width": "15%" },
                { "width": "15%" },
                { "width": "5%" },
                { "width": "50%" },
                { "width": "15%" }
            ]
        });
```

le annadi una funcion q con el evento de resize me funciona bien pk m las acomoda pero quisiera q funcionara siempre

```
$(window).resize(function () {
            $('.d-table').each(function () {
                $(this).columns.adjust().draw();
            });
        });
```

he probado con setInterval y un each dentro para estar haciendo lo siempre y tampoco m funciona...
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

encontre una funcion q si m funciono,

```
setInterval(function () {
            tables.columns.adjust().draw();
        }, 300);
```